# Passing a PHP array to a JavaScript array inside a PHP function

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, ajax

I know this question has been asked a lot on Stack Overflow, although I can't find any solution that can be applied to my problem.

I'm working on a platform that regroups all videos and pictures of my company (I'm taking back the project after my ex-coworker), my issue is on the Lightbox that displays the pictures.

I have a PHP function that returns HTML/CSS/JavaScript in string format like this:

```
$block = '<div id="myModal" class="modal" style="margin:auto">'
            .'<span style="float:right;margin-right:33px"><a href="'.HTTP_IHM_PATH.'Suppression.php?id='.$records[$i]['Access_Key'].'" onclick="return confirm(\'Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir continuer cette suppression ? Elle sera définitive.\');"><img src="'.HTTP_IMG_PATH.'corbeille.jpg" style="width:20px;height:auto;"></a></span>'
            .'<span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()" style="color:#585858; font-size:60px;float:right;">&times;</span>'
[...]
return $block;
```

I call the function like this : `<?php echo function() ?>`

In here, I have a PHP array `$records` that contains all information about the pictures I want to display in my LightBox, I want later in my code to use those information into my JavaScript functions.

I've heard that I can translate the array in JavaScript by using `<script>var records = <?php json_encode($records) ?></script>` but it doesn't work!

In the end what I want to do is when the user clicks on a picture, it opens up my LightBox and for every pictures he is watching, I want to call my PHP function `UpdateViews()` that add 1 to the number of views of the picture.

I tried using Ajax, but since it's pretty new to me I may be doing stupid mistakes (this is still in string format in the variable `$block`):

```
$block .= '//getSlideIndex returns slideIndex which is the id of the <img/>
$(\'#\' + getSlideIndex()).on(\'click\', function (){
                    alert("Ok onclick" + records[getSlideIndex()]["Access_Key"];
                    //"Access_Key" is the property I need (primary key of the table)
                    $.ajax({
                        type:\'GET\',
                        url: \'/picture.php\',
                        data: {id=\' + records[getSlideIndex()]["Access_Key"] + \'},
                        success: function(data){
                            alert(\'success\' + data);
                        },
                        error: function(exception){
                            alert(\'Exception: \' + exception);
                        }
                    });
                    e.preventDefault();
                });';
```

NOTE: My ex-coworker already used some Ajax in his code, so at the time I'm on this page, a `$_GET` is already set: Will I be able to make my ajax work in this case?

Thank you if you read until this point, I hope you can help me get on the right track.

Comment: To be *that* guy: please think about seperating front- and backend, fetch your JSON with an endpoint which is the PHP part. That way, it won't become a complicated mess like this. Sorry for being pedantic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've heard that I can translate the array in javascript by using `<script>var records = <?php json_encode($records) ?></script>` but it doesn't work !

That doesn't work because you didn't `echo` the result, you're simply running the JSON process and then discarding the result. Add an echo:

```
<script>var records = <?php echo json_encode($records) ?></script>
```

and contrary to the other answer, do not try to `JSON.parse` this because it is already a valid JavaScript object.

Edit: if you're trying to concatenate the JSON to a response string then don't use `<?php` tags, instead you can do:

```
$block .= '<script>var records = ' . json_encode($records) . '; </script>';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I still get an error though : `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'` . How can I make the code interpret PHP in a <script> markup ? Since all of this code is activated by an `echo function()`

Answer (score 0):

> I've heard that I can translate the array in javascript by using `<script>var records = <?php json_encode($records) ?></script>` but it doesn't work !

That's pretty close. This will make a JavaScript **variable** that's a [JSON string](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp). You can then use JavaScript's [JSON parse](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp) to convert that JSON string back into an Array/Object.

Once you do all of that, you will have a JavaScript array with data delivered from your PHP array.